# Base Class Collection Thread Safe Question

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, autofac

I have the following base class:

```
public class ReportBase {
    protected List<ReportDataTable> ReportDataTables { get;set; }
}
```

We have this report base being used on multiple report classes - such as this:

```
public class MyCustomReport : ReportBase {
    public MyCustomReport() {}
    public void GenerateReport(string filters) {
      ReportDataTables = new List<ReportDataTable>();
      //etc etc etc
    }
}
```

We are using autofac to dynamically swap out these various reports as needed for generation.

```
 public class ReportService : IReportService
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<Lazy<IReportGeneratorService, IReportGeneratorMetadata>> _reportGeneratorServices;

        public ReportService(IEnumerable<Lazy<IReportGeneratorService, IReportGeneratorMetadata>> reportGeneratorServices)
        {
            _reportGeneratorServices = reportGeneratorServices;
        }

        public TestMethod(){
          //Not thread safe when called inside a Parallel.ForEach
          var reportServiceLazyLoad = _reportGeneratorServices.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Metadata.Name == myMetaDataName);
        }
     }
```

the problem we are encountering is that when we run a parallel.foreach and call the "TestMethod" for the same report type with different filters the underlying `ReportDataTables` is populated with data from multiple reports instead of specifically for the one being called. I'm not sure how to segment it so that it only loads up data for that specific service, it seems that when its in a parallel for each its mixing in results from other threads or something.

Not sure if this makes sense, the above code isn't exact but generalized to give a general idea. i can clarify more if necessary - thanks for all your help.

**More Details To Illustrate the Problem**

the code below i believe is illustrating the issue i'm encountering. I'm trying to dynamically pull the service out of the collection but i need it to be a new instance, not a reference, the problem is that when this occurs inside a parallel.foreach its using the same reference and updating data inaccurately, if it was using a seperate isolated instance i wouldn't have data being mixed across - if this makes sense?

```
public class Test {

    private readonly IEnumerable<Lazy<IReportGeneratorService, IReportGeneratorMetadata>> _reportGeneratorServices;

    public Test(IEnumerable<Lazy<IReportGeneratorService, IReportGeneratorMetadata>> reportGeneratorServices)
        {
            _reportGeneratorServices = reportGeneratorServices;
        }


     public void CheckRefEquality(){
           var t1 = _reportGeneratorServices.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Metadata.Name == "MyReportService");

            var t2 = _reportGeneratorServices.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Metadata.Name == "MyReportService");

            var t3 = Object.ReferenceEquals(t1.Value, t2.Value);
           //t3 returns true - how can i forcibly create a new instance instead of pulling the same instance, this is what i believe is causing issues.

   }

}
```

**Update per Erics Example**

In your sample code below:

```
fooService.GitErDone("Bar", "filter_1");
fooService.GitErDone("Bar", "filter_2");
fooService.GitErDone("Baz", "filter_3");
fooService.GitErDone("Bar", "filter_4");
fooService.GitErDone("Baz", "filter_5");
```

you said the above creates two instances, one per registration

what i'm trying to do is essentially the equivilanet of this - assuming each of the calls below happen concurrently in a parallel.foreach:

```
fooService.GitErDone("ReportService1", "filter_1");
fooService.GitErDone("ReportService1", "filter_2");
fooService.GitErDone("ReportService1", "filter_3");
fooService.GitErDone("ReportService1", "filter_4");
fooService.GitErDone("ReportService1", "filter_5");
```

Where essentially every one of the calls above uses a unique instance of ReportService1 - the problem is that when its sharing the instance it appears the underlying base class collection "ReportDataTables" is getting mixed data from different filters.

**This may be a better representation**

```
Parallel.ForEach(filters, f => {

var report =  _reportsCollection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Metadata.Name == "AlwaysTheSameReport");

// report should be a new instance, however when i run this in reality its always the same instance instead of a new one
report.GetErDone(f);

});
```

Comment: `TestMethod()` only shows code that iterates the private field `_reportGeneratorServices`, which canot be altered after assignment in the constructor as it's `readonly`. I don't see any reason why that code would not be thread safe.

Comment: So i dont know if this matters but the variable myMetaDataName that is being called is usually the same, meaning its pulling the same service multiple times in the parallel.foreach, the reason why its pulling the same one is that each time its pulling it its using different filters, but i'm wondering if that may be the cause of this as well.

Comment: If each report generator service is configured as a singleton, that would be your problem... not in TestMethod() as shown in your question, but if TestMethod() calls GenerateReport(), that could well be your problem. A single instance of your report generator service would have that method called in parallel.

Comment: thanks for the info - how can i pull the service as a new instance from the enumerable<lazy<t> collection instead of pulling the same instance? this is where i get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t3 = Object.ReferenceEquals(t1.Value, t2.Value);
//t3 returns true - how can i forcibly create a new instance instead of pulling the same instance, this is what i believe is causing issues.
```

Your dependency injection factory is creating singletons, meaning one unique object instance per type.

Autofac supports a variety of [scope strategies](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html). Instance per Dependency Scope seems suitable to this scenario.

An alternative is to make the method `GenerateReport(string filters)` thread safe (e.g. by moving `protected List<ReportDataTable> ReportDataTables { get;set; }` to a local variable of that method).

UPDATE

Based on the following test, injected instances work as expected when filtered using metadata, both single and multi-threaded:

```
using Autofac;

namespace AutoFacTest
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void DoWork(string filter);
    }
    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        static int instanceCounter = 0;
        private int thisInstanceNumber;
        public Foo()
        {
            thisInstanceNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref instanceCounter);
            Console.WriteLine($"Constructing Foo #{thisInstanceNumber}");
        }
        public void DoWork(string filter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Doing work in instance {thisInstanceNumber} with filter {filter}.");
        }
    }
    public class FooMetadata
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class DoStuffWithFoo
    {
        readonly IEnumerable<Lazy<IFoo, FooMetadata>> _foos;
        public DoStuffWithFoo(IEnumerable<Lazy<IFoo, FooMetadata>> foos)
        {
            _foos = foos;
        }
        public void GitErDone(string metaName, string filter)
        {
            var foo = _foos.First(f => f.Metadata.Name == metaName);
            foo.Value.DoWork(filter);
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        private static IContainer? Container { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MultiThreaded();
            //SingleThreaded_WorksAsExpected();
        }

        static void MultiThreaded_WorksAsExpected()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<DoStuffWithFoo>();

            var filters = Enumerable
                .Range(0, 100)
                .Select(n => $"Filter_{n}")
                .ToArray();

            builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
                .WithMetadata<FooMetadata>(m => m.For(am => am.Name, "Bar"))
                .As<IFoo>()
                ;
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
                .WithMetadata<FooMetadata>(m => m.For(am => am.Name, "Baz"))
                .As<IFoo>()
                ;
            Container = builder.Build();

            var fooService = Container.Resolve<DoStuffWithFoo>();

            int counter = 0;
            var names = new string[] { "Bar", "Baz" };
            Parallel.ForEach(filters, f =>
            {
                fooService.GitErDone(names[Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) % 2], f);
            });
        }

        static void SingleThreaded_WorksAsExpected()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<DoStuffWithFoo>();

            builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
                .WithMetadata<FooMetadata>(m => m.For(am => am.Name, "Bar"))
                .As<IFoo>()
                ;
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
                .WithMetadata<FooMetadata>(m => m.For(am => am.Name, "Baz"))
                .As<IFoo>()
                ;
            Container = builder.Build();

            var fooService = Container.Resolve<DoStuffWithFoo>();

            // These construct exactly 2 instances of Foo, one for each registration.
            // Logging in the method DoWork() indicates the expected instance is used.
            fooService.GitErDone("Bar", "filter_1");
            fooService.GitErDone("Bar", "filter_2");
            fooService.GitErDone("Baz", "filter_3");
            fooService.GitErDone("Bar", "filter_4");
            fooService.GitErDone("Baz", "filter_5");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i've checked into thread scope previously but the challenge i'm having is how to code it so that i can still pull the service dynamically. in their example they show "var thisThreadsInstance = threadLifetime.Resolve<MyThreadScopedComponent>();" - but i'm not sure how to change/convert this to pull from the collection since i'm pulling the report service dynamic based upon meta data.

Comment: The other option is to make that method thread safe (updated the answer accordingly).

Comment: Thanks - this is something i've considered but that base class is used across so many services it would require massive refactoring, its my last resort, something  i'd like to try to avoid unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Did you look at Instance per Dependency? Actually, that sounds like the right fit (I didn't notice on first read that it's the same as transient scope in other DI frameworks).

Comment: Hi Eric - we are using InstanceAsDependency currently: 

            builder.RegisterType<MyReport1Service>()
               .As<IReportGeneratorService>().InstancePerDependency()
               .WithMetadata<IReportGeneratorMetadata>(m => m.For(em => em.Name, "MyReport1Service"));

            builder.RegisterType<MyReport2Service>()
               .As<IReportGeneratorService>().InstancePerDependency()
               .WithMetadata<IReportGeneratorMetadata>(m => m.For(em => em.Name, "MyReport2Service"));

Comment: @99823 I created a test (added to answer) that demonstrates `InstancePerDependency()` (which is the default if not specified) indeed creates a new instance for each object requested.

Comment: Hi @Eric - thank you for investing time in assisting me with this, it really is greatly apprecaited, i too live in Irvine and would sincerely like to treat you to a coffee or something if you are interested as a thank you for your time.  The sample you provided would indeed work, however the difference is that I need to load from Enumberable<Lazy< by the meta dataname because we are implementing numerous report services and then dynamically loading them upon use, so its not as straight forward as simply specifying the service name - as its more dynamic in nature, hope this makes sense.

Comment: this here gives a basic example of our use case, however instead of for various loggers we are using it for various reports: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-lazyt-tmetadata-in-dependency-injection/

Comment: Edited my example to be closer to your case. Still works as I would expect.

Comment: hi eric - i see why yours is working any mine isn't. the problem is that im trying to call the same service with different filters, whereas you are calling multpile services - so you call 2 unique services and get 2 unique instances. I am calling the same service say 100 times, but different filters per that same service, i need to have a unique instance per call, not per registration. the problem is as i am calling the same service say 100 times that underlying base class collection is mixing data from different filter parameters instead of keeping it isolated per call, does this make sense?

Comment: I've updated my question with more details explaining your version vs what i'm trying to achieve, thank you again very much

Comment: Disregard all my new comments - your solution / code sample helped me solve my problem. thank you so much!! this has been a pain for some time so i'm super appreciative - let me buy you a coffee lol